# Converting vector in NED to ECEF?

Tags: coordinate-system, vector, convert, latitude-longitude, wgs84

I have a geodetic WGS84 position, lat, lon, alt, and direction cosines from the same point, uN, uE, uD. I'm brand new to geodetic/ecef conventions. How do I take a vector (say, a unit vector with magnitude 1), with direction uN, uE, uD, and represent it in [ECEF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECEF)?

I can find a lot of information online about going the reverse way: ECEF to NED, but nothing about NED to ECEF.

I was already able to convert my geodetic position to ECEF, but I'm pretty sure I'll need a direction cosine matrix to convert the NED vector to ECEF, right?

But isn't latitude geodetic?

Would I need to convert to geocentric to perform the basis transformation and create the direction cosine matrix for NED -> ECEF?

Can't for the life of me figure out how to represent vectors like these in X,Y,Z

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_tangent_plane_coordinates#Local_north,_east,_down_(NED)_coordinates